# Testing website bandwidth

Tags: php, bandwidth

I would like to make a script that boosts my website's bandwidth to check the monthly allowance is working correctly.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i>2000$i++) {
  //largest jpg on the website
  file_put_contents("tmp.jpg", file_get_contents("http://someurl/tmp.jpg"));
  unlink("tmp.jpg");
}
?>
```

Would the above code work in the way I would like it too or because it's the same file, does the server not 'download' it again?

Comment: Apart from wasting bandwith, what is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: @Jocelyn The idea is to waste bandwidth.

Comment: Exactly that - that is exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: Just asking whether this will work correctly before I start using it - or any suggestions as to how do it in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the second post [here](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=291686), `file_get_contents` does not cache PHP files. I have no reason to think it should.